# not able to set height of vertical navigation bar to the full page in CSS

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to make a vertical navigation bar. I have made a navbar.I want to set it's height to full page but i am not able to do that even when is set `height:100%` in CSS. I want content like para to be displayed on its left side.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

ul li {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul li a {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  pos
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

ul li a:active {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  color: red;
}

div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news" target="_blank">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" tartget="_blank">About</a></li>
</ul>


<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam aspernatur qui tenetur dicta, aperiam harum saepe, fuga quae distinctio corporis quas amet minima magnam, excepturi cupiditate at sunt sit cum.</div>
```

I tried to change the `display:` parameter of the unordered list to `display:inline` and also the `display:` parameter of div tag to `display:inline` How do I set the height to full page and also display content on its left side.

Comment: `100%` of what? If you want 100% of the screens height: `100vh`. if you want 100% of the entire website, you need to either use `flexbox`, `css-grid` or `position absolute + top: 0 + bottom: 0`

Comment: For easy development use bootstrap and divide things in column

Comment: @Abhi not helpful. It will neither solve the issue nor is it required. Plenty reason not to sue external libraries.

Comment: It is a suggestion and why can't it solve the issue of alignment?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `height:100%;` it means that you want that element to be 100% of its parent which in your case is body, and as height is not defined for it so it is auto. all you need to do is to add `min-height:100vh` for the body. It will solve your problem for full height navbar.

Now your next objective is to make the text to wrap around it, which can achieved by floating your navbar to left. This will make the next elements to wrap around it.

Setting div to `display:inline;` won't be a good thing to do just for achieving this result, because the moment you add next div it will start creating problems.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul li a {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

ul li a:active {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news" target="_blank">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" tartget="_blank">About</a></li>
  </ul>


  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam aspernatur qui tenetur dicta, aperiam harum saepe, fuga quae distinctio corporis quas amet minima magnam, excepturi cupiditate at sunt sit cum.</div>

  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam aspernatur qui tenetur dicta, aperiam harum saepe, fuga quae distinctio corporis quas amet minima magnam, excepturi cupiditate at sunt sit cum.</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) or for understanding you can do it like this also:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 20vw;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    
    ul li {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: grey;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    ul li a {
      font-family: monospace;
      color: white;
      font-size: 23px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      padding: 10px;
      pos
    }
    
    ul li a:hover {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
    
    ul li a:active {
      background-color: cadetblue;
      color: red;
    }
    
    div {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="float: left; width: 20vw;">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news" target="_blank">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" tartget="_blank">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right;width: 75vw">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam aspernatur qui tenetur dicta, aperiam harum saepe, fuga quae distinctio corporis quas amet minima magnam, excepturi cupiditate at sunt sit cum.</div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```